# Is there a documented list of types like "bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object"

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to find some documented list of types like: bpy.types.VIEW3D_*, bpy.types.3D*, bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT* and other types that relate to parts of the UI, especially those that relate to where I can prepend/append menu items.

In this particular case: a new RMB menu item to add a custom property and paste as a driver.  But in general to find out where these are documented or how to obtain a list.  If I type bpy.types.[escape] into the console the resulting list is too long.

Something like:

```
for t in bpy.types:
    print(t)
```

Comment: `dir(bpy.types)`

Comment: @scurest - danke!